# Passing the search term from SearchHandler to ContentPage in Xamarin Forms 4

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I'm trying to make use of the new SearchHandler implemented as part of Xamarin Forms 4. I've found it pretty easy so far to get suggestions populated but now I want to raise an event, or follow the suggested method of handling when a search is confirmed.

```
public class FoodSearchHandler: SearchHandler
{
    IFoodDataStore dataStore = new FoodDataStore();

    protected override void OnQueryConfirmed()
    {
        base.OnQueryConfirmed();
        // What to do here?
    }

    protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue)
        {
            // Populate suggestions
            ItemsSource = dataStore.GetSuggestions(newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            ItemsSource = null;
        } 
    }
}

public partial class FoodsPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<Food> Foods = new ObservableCollection<Food>();

    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Wire up the search handler
        Shell.SetSearchHandler(this, new FoodSearchHandler());
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, althought the [alpha docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell) mention the search handler they don't contain any details on how to use it and the sample apps only demonstrate populating the suggestions.

Does anyone out there have a pointer to offer on how I should be notifying my ContentPage that my SearchHandler confirmed a search?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Controls/ShellContent.xaml.cs You can refer this demo.

Comment: Thanks @LucasZhang-MSFT but I don't see the Search confirmed event being handled in that example. It just calls the base class method. Is there some magic convention handling happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reading the Shell docs some more, it seems what I want to do in this situation is use of Shell's new [Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell#navigation) and navigate to a route passing the search text as a query, for example:

```
protected override void OnQueryConfirmed()
{
    base.OnQueryConfirmed();

    var shell = Application.Current.MainPage as Shell;
    shell.GoToAsync($"app:///fructika/search?query={Query}", true);
}
```

N.B. It doesn't look like [passing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell#passing-data) works right now or if it does I'm doing it wrong but I'll raise a separate question about that.